# Accessing Security Items in App Extension iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, security

I have an action app extension. I would like to access some keys that I added in the main app, so that I can use them for encryption/decryption. These keys were added in via `SecItemAdd`.

I know the keys exist and the functions for extracting them work, since they work in the main app. However, in the app extension, I get error code -25300, which means SecItem not found. I added the Security framework to the app extension, but besides from that I didn't change anything. How can I make sure that I can access these keys in the app extension?

Comment: This may help you - http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions

Comment: This is for user defaults though, right? But the stuff added in the keychain through `SecItemAdd` is different, right?

Comment: Actually, you were right, I had forgotten to share the keychain.

Comment: Good, it helped you!